# How to properly use style.display in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have two divs whose role is the one of a burger menu. One of them has the property `display:block`, and the other one has `display:none;`.
After I click one one `div` the `nav` opens and the div's display property turns to none, however when I use the similar block of code to make the other `div` visible the code doesn't work (by applying `display: block` throught JavaScript).
When I check the console, it shows the the div's property has changed from none to block, but I can't locate the `div` with my mouse or see it.

code below:

HTML

```
 <div class="burger">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="secondBurger">
    <div class="line3"></div>
    <div class="line4"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.burger div {
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.secondBurger div {
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.secondBurger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger .line {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 5px);
}

.burger .line2 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -5.5px);
}

#secondBurger .line3 {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 1px);
}

#secondBurger .line4 {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 1px);
}
```

JavaScript

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".bubbles");
  const bubbles = document.querySelectorAll(".bubbles p");
  const mainNav = document.querySelector(".mainNav");
  const main = document.querySelector(".main");

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("bubbles-active");
    bubbles.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (nav.classList.contains("bubbles-active")) {
        document.querySelector(".line").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".line2").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".line3").style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector(".line4").style.display = "block";
      } else if (main.classList.contains("main")) {
        document.querySelector(".line").style.backgroundColor = "";
        document.querySelector(".line2").style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Codepen

```
codepen.io/jelaaxo/pen/JjGQMPM
```

Comment: bubbles is `.bubbles p`, whats it got to do with `.burger`, seems like your looping over the wrong thing. please show rest of dom

Comment: Hey! The idea was to change the first burgers display to none once the nav (bubbles) opens, at the same time (when the nav is opened) i want the other burger to change it's display to block. I tried writing the code as a reaction to clicking the first burger (and not as a reaction when the nav opens) but nothing changes.